# Notes and Attachments files size

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, administration

When I'm uploading file from lightning out (apex page) and attach it to my record in Notes & Attachments related list salesforce doesn't show file size. It shows only when I'm uploading from salesforce page. How to show file size?[image]

Comment: are you talking about the standard related list? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @sanketkumar just added. Yes it's standard related list

Comment: how are you uploading the file using lightning:out? Can you add the minimal required as well?

Comment: @sanketkumar I'm uploading file as attachment from vf page, but when I'm uploading file inside salesforce it upload file as ContentDocument. I guess it's main problem and I need to upload file like ContentDocument

Comment: That is indeed correct, Files and Attachments are shown in different way in Related list on record

Comment: @kurunve I queried these files and file that was uploaded inside SF is queried like ContentDocument and files that were uploaded from lightning out are Attachments. And all these files (Attachments and ContentDocuments are in one Notes&Attachments related list)

Answer (score 2):

Bodylength - Size of the file (in bytes) of the [attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm).

Unfortunately, You cannot add this field on notes and attachment-related list as this is not customizable.

[image]

The workaround is you can create a simple custom Lightning Component to show attachment as a table.